# Laravel former bundle

Tags: laravel, installation, bundle

I'm trying to install the former bundle in laravel 3 and try it out.
I was following the installation instructions until I got to this point:

> Now as Laravel 3 doesn't automatically checkout Composer dependencies,
>   you'll have to go into the bundles/former folder and do a composer
>   install (after that I'll leave you guys alone, promise).

Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not really sure what to do here?
What I did try was cd into bundles/former and then tried:

```
$ php artisan bundle:install composer
```

to no avail. Got the following error: *Could not open input file: artisan*

Again forgive my ignorance as I'm relatively new to laravel. If anyone one could tell me how to get his bundle installed I would be very great full.

Comment: Composer is an package manager for PHP, not for Laravel (though Laravel 4 uses Composer). try 'php composer install' or just 'composer install'. If this doesnt work you may need to install composer first...

Answer (score 2):

Composer is not a laravel bundle , so you will not be able to install it by placing artisan command.

And also , you have to run all commands of artisan from the root of your laravel project.

Note : Just check if there is a file artisan.php in your current directory. That's the easiest way to know you are in the right place or not.

And about Former.

You have to install composer first . To know and work with composer , you can try this [nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-package-management-with-composer/).

After that follow the instructions given in Former bundle.

I believe that will be fine.

Comment: It's works, run all commands of artisan from the root of your laravel project

Answer (score 1):

"you'll have to go into the bundles/former folder"

```
cd /path/to/bundles/former
```

"and do a composer install"

```
composer install
```